# Toggle terminal shortcut not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, non-ascii-characters

Recently after I've shifted to a new workstation, my shortcut for toggling vscode's integrated terminal doesn't seem to be working. The current shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+A` and it's correctly set in the shortcuts panel, but using that key combination results in this weird character, `Á`. The issue is not only with `A` but with other letters as well. For example `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S` results in `§`, `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+D` results in Ð. The weird thing is that it doesn't **always happen**. And I am not sure when it changes its behavior. Any lead would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Right after I've posted this question, I typed the same key combination again. But this time for some reason I stopped midway and only typed `Ctrl+Shift`. For a brief moment, I saw something on the right edge of the screen. I typed the same keys again and saw that by clicking `Ctrl+Shift` I was toggling between two keyboard layouts, `English (US)` and `English (International)`. That was the primary reason why typing `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+A` resulted in `Á`. The fix was to remove that layout.

1. Type `Time & Language` in your Settings,
2. you should see a `Preferred languages` section which lists all the distinct keyboard layouts.
3. Click on `English (United States)` and then click `Options`
4. Scroll down, click on `US (International)`, and select remove.

That should do the trick. Hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

on a UK keyboard this worked for me
BTW the key is: CTRL+`  i.e. ctrl key + a backtick

```
    [
    
// switch focus between terminal and editor
{
    "key": "ctrl+oem_8",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+oem_8",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Kubuntu in a PT-BR keyboard. I replaced `"ctrl+oem_8` with `"ctrl+'"` from the previous answer and worked just fine.

Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and open `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts(JSON)` (without the Default) and copy the two key bindings shown below.

If you haven't edited this file before it should look like this:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+'",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+'",
        "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
]
```